# Grep for multiple strings with escaped pipe in each

Tags: regex, bash

I'm using Gitbash within Windows. I want to grep for a set of strings, each of which ends with a |

I think I can do each one singly with a backslash to escape the pipe:

```
grep abcdef\| filename.tsv
```

But to do them all together I end up with:

```
grep 'abcdef\|\|uvwxyz\|' filename.tsv
```

which fails. Any ideas?

I could just do each string individually and then concatenate the resulting files, but it would take days.

Comment: Beware multiple levels of quoting.  When you type `grep abcdef\| filename.tsv`, the backslash keeps the shell from interpreting the pipe and trying to feed the output of `grep abcdef` to the command `filename.tsv`.  But what `grep` actually gets as its first argument is just `abcdef|` with no backslash - which is what you want with basic `grep` regexes; un-backslashed pipes are taken literally.  When you put the argument into single quotation marks, now the backslash gets passed to `grep`, which completely changes what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In basic posix regexes - which are used by grep - you must not escape the literal `|`. However you need to escape the `|` if it is used as a regex syntax element to specify alternatives.

The following expression should work:

```
grep 'abcdef|\|uvwxyz|' filename.tsv
```

Answer (score 4):

An ERE might be the way to go, for easier readability.

```
egrep '(abcdef|uvwxyz)[|]' filename.tsv
```

This lets you manage your string list a little more easily, and "escapes" the trailing vertical bar by putting it inside a range. (This works for dots, asterisks, etc, as well.)

If `egrep` isn't available on your system, you can check to see if your existing grep includes a `-E` option for extended regexes.

Comment: Looks better than the basic posix regex that I've suggested! You are right, egrep should be used here.

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated (use `grep -E`). If your motivation for using `egrep` is to save a character, I'd suggest using `\|` instead of `[|]` :)

Comment: @TomFenech, I periodically see people mention that egrep is deprecated, but I've never seen mention of that in any of the documentation on systems that I use.  Regarding the or bar, I often use ranges to escape special characters because they work the same way in BRE and ERE.

Comment: From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/egrep.html): "The name _egrep_ is an obsolescent version equivalent to _grep_ **-E**."

Comment: (but yeah, I take your point about the consistent behaviour within the brackets)

Comment: "obsolescent" is not the same as "deprecated"... `egrep` also has the advantage of working on pre-POSIX systems (when it was a separate binary instead of a different mode of operation of the same code).

Comment: @Mark, OK, another quote from the same page: "Applications should migrate to the grep -E command." and from the GNU grep manual on my system: "These variants [egrep and fgrep] are deprecated". Personally, I would say that we should be using `grep -E` in our answers and suggesting `egrep` as a backup option, rather than the other way round.

Comment: The [GNU grep documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) does indeed describe egrep and fgrep as deprecated.  Of course, we have no idea whether the OP's system is running GNU grep or some other variant. Point taken about the order of recommendations, I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all for this, much appreciated. @hek2mgl 's first solution works perfectly well, but next time, when I'm feeling braver, I'll try it again with grep -e using ghoti 's suggestion, which is more elegant with a long list of patterns.

Answer (score 2):

There are two competing effects here which you may be confusing. Firstly, the `|` must be escaped or quoted so that it is not interpreted by the shell. Secondly, depending on which regex mode you are using, escaping/unescaping the pipe changes whether it is a literal character or a metacharacter.

I would suggest that you change your pattern to this:

```
grep 'abcdef|\|uvwxyz|' file
```

In basic regex mode, an escaped pipe `\|` is a regex OR, so this matches either pattern followed by a literal pipe.

Alternatively, if all your patterns end in a pipe and you have more than just two, perhaps you could use this:

```
grep -E '(abc|def|ghi)\|' file
```

In extended mode, escaping the pipe has the opposite effect, so this pattern matches any of the sequences of letters followed by a literal pipe.

Comment: OP likely has the `egrep` command, which defaults to `-E` mode (they were traditionally separate commands, but these days are more commonly the same one with different defaults).

Comment: @MarkReed Indeed, GNU's `egrep` is simply [a shell script](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/egrep.sh) which calls `grep -E`. However, this means that `grep -E` is - slightly - faster than `egrep` since it does not require to spawn an extra shell.  That's why I would prefer `grep -E` - at least in shell scripts.